# string manipulation in c# arrayindex out of range exception why it is occur?

Tags: c#, string, substring, indexoutofboundsexception

```
using System.IO;
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string s1="iamamamok";
        string s2="mam";
        int i=0,j=0;
        int count=0,countchar=0;

        while(j<s2.Length)
        {
            while(i<s1.Length)
            {
                if(s1[i]==s2[j])
                {
                    countchar++;
                    j++;
                    if(countchar==(s2.Length))
                    {
                        count +=1;
                        j=0;
                        countchar=0;
                    }

                }
                else
                {
                    j=0;
                    countchar=0;
                }
                i++;
                if(i==s1.Length)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    Console.Write(count);

    }
}
```

when i try to run this code it will give array index out of range but i try to cover all possible cases for these strings please explain why this error occur???????????????????????????????????????????????

Comment: Can you state what you want your program to do?

Comment: Because your code is not the code in question This code gets stuck in an infinite loop.

Answer (score -1):

You are incrementing `j` in your inner loop and then using it again with no check to see if it's less than the length of the string.

(for future reference, please post the error message including the line where the error occurs as it helps others debug)

Comment: This program run into endless loop instead of index out of range exception